# DataTable doesn't remember paginated page after edit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I've been using DataTable serverside processing. My datatable has edit column. When edit link click jQuery dialog box will appear and after submit dialog box will close and ajax.reload call. But when I'm doing this in paging if I edit user in 2nd page after ajax.reload it redirect to 1st page instead of staying 2nd page.

How can I avoid that?

This is my edit column:

```
 {
     "data": "id",
     "render": function (id, type, full, meta) {
         return '<a  class="editUser" href="url' + id + '"></a>';
     }
 },
```

This is editwindow function part

```
thisTable.ajax.reload();
```

Please help how to keep paging with ajax.reload?

Comment: found solution :)   thisTable.ajax.reload(null, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding this as an answer, since the OP didn't have enough rep to add it as an answer himself:

Change this line:
`thisTable.ajax.reload();`
to
`thisTable.ajax.reload(null, false);`

Comment: thank you, can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432687/datatable-serverside-process-how-to-remeber-checked-boxes-on-pagination